# How to detect the current user for an audit log?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, authentication, active-directory

I'm working in Entity Framework 5.  We're using Microsoft Active Directory for user authentication.  We're using a proper n-tier architecture, so for the most part, the business layer is blissfully unaware of the UI.

Now we have a requirement to keep a full audit trail: every time any write operation happens on the database, we have to save it to our audit log, along with who made the change.

Catching the write should be relatively simple; I'll just override `SaveChanges()` in my data context and use the `ObjectStateManager` to find all the inserts, updates and deletes.  The real issue will be detecting who the current user is, since authentication is done on the presentation layer, and the business layer DLL will be hosted on IIS, servicing any number of client processes.

Is there some way to detect the authentication credentials that were used by the client, inside the business layer?  I definitely do not want to have to pass user ID to every interface in the API!

(FWIW, I'm also using EntityFramework.Extended, which supposedly has some native AuditLog capabilities, but the [documentation](https://github.com/loresoft/EntityFramework.Extended/wiki/Audit-Log) is woefully inadequate.  Anyone with any experience using this successfully?  Could it help?)

Comment: Is the presentation layer a trusted subsystem of the business layer?

Comment: I take it this is an **intranet** application?

Comment: @Grumbler85 I don't really understand the question.  How would it be trusted?  The presentation layer has a reference to the BL, not the other way around.

Comment: Well does the presentation layer act as the user (so does it delegate the user credentials) or does it act in an own security context (some_user@yourdomain)?

Comment: @Shaul, since you're using Windows Authentication already, you should be able to simply use Windows Authentication on the deployed business layer and thus know the user that is accessing that session. Just disable Anonymous access and require Windows Authentication.

Comment: @BigM Will that work even through a browser?  From my previous usage of DLLs in IIS, I've seen the BL has the same static context for all threads/clients.  Will each thread reflect a different AD user, according to who's logged in on the client?

Comment: @Grumbler85 I'm going to swallow my embarrassment at not knowing the answer to that question, and ask you: how would I know the difference?  The controllers are decorated with the [Authorize] attribute.  Does that tell you anything?

Comment: @Shaul, yes, you can access the credentials from the `Request.LogonUserIdentity`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could consider passing the end-user's identity out-of-band, rather than adding it to every method signature.

For example, if you're using WCF you could create a behavior that injects a custom SOAP header client-side, and processes the custom header server-side.

**UPDATE**

Comments to the question appear to imply that the DLL is directly accessed from the ASP.NET MVC application, not via a web service.  I had assumed from your statement that:

> the business layer DLL will be hosted on IIS, servicing any number of client processes

that it was a web service called from multiple ASP.NET MVC applications.

If it's just a DLL included in your ASP.NET MVC application, it's very simple.

- `HttpContext.Current.User` will contain the identity of the connected client.
- Rather than using HttpContext in the business tier, you should ensure that `Thread.CurrentPrincipal` is set to the same principal as `HttpContext.Current.User`.

  If you are using an ASP.NET `RoleProvider`, this will be done for you automatically.  If not, you may need to do it manually, e.g. in the AuthorizeRequest event handler in global.asax.

Then in the business tier you access the end-user identity as `Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name`.

Comment: We're using ASP.NET MVC, HTML 5.  How would you do that?

Comment: How are you communicating between the presentation tier (ASP.NET MVC) and the business tier?  Is the business tier hosted in a IIS web service (How is the presentation tier authenticating the end user (Windows auth or Forms auth)?

Comment: It's just a DLL included in the ASP.NET MVC application.  I'll give it a whirl and see if that works.  Thanks!

Comment: @Joe It's not advised to use Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity since it is mutable and you have to concern yourself with synchronizing static states between Thread and ClaimsPrincipal.

This article discussed it further;
https://davidpine.net/blog/principal-architecture-changes/

Also this approach is slightly different but is the same in principle;
https://gist.github.com/cherrydev/5c7168c8947eb1a1b5b8

However both examples are at the Service layer and hence this needs to be adjusted to be available to SaveChanges within theDbContext.

Comment: @Sigex - I read the blog you linked, and while the author's entitled to his opinion (publically static mutable state, oh my ... this was never a good idea), I don't agree.  It's essentially thread-static state, and while ASP.NET Core devs may have made different design decisions, I don't see any problem with using Thread.CurrentPrincipal in a .NET Framework app.   In the .NET Framework, CAS can prevent unauthorized code from modifying the state, though these days most code runs with full trust.

Comment: @Joe, I agree I use this for .Net Core. Sorry for the misunderstanding on the Framework being used.

Answer (score 3):

Provided you've configured authentication appropriately (e.g. Forms or Windows authentication), then `Thread.CurrentPrincipal` is guaranteed to refer to the user making the request.